# PHP/DOMXpath/DOMDocument - Unable to parse specific links

Tags: php, domdocument, domxpath

Here is my code, you can copy and paste it to start runing, it's complete for test:

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.sportsdirect.com/ladies/ladies-underwear";

libxml_use_internal_errors(true); 
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$n  = $xpath->query('//div[@class="s-producttext-top-wrapper"]');
$l  = $xpath->query('//div[@class="s-producttext-top-wrapper"]/a');
$p  = $xpath->query('//div[@class="s-largered"]');
$nl = $xpath->query('//a[@class="swipeNextClick NextLink"]');
$NextLink  = $nl->item(0)->getAttribute("data-dcp");

$item = 0;
foreach ($n as $entry) {
    $Name      = $entry->nodeValue;
    $Link      = $l->item($item)->getAttribute("href");

    $Price     = $p->item($item)->nodeValue;

    $Find = array('Â£');
    $Replace   = array('');

    $Price = str_replace($Find, $Replace, $Price);      

    echo "Name: $Name - Link: $Link - Price: $Price - $NextLink<br>";
$item++;    

}
?>
```

This is parsing all the products from `http://www.sportsdirect.com/ladies/ladies-underwear` which are on the FIRST page.

Here is the link for the second page `http://www.sportsdirect.com/ladies/ladies-underwear#dcp=2&dppp=100&OrderBy=rank`

And when i execute this code to get all the products from the SECOND page:

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.sportsdirect.com/ladies/ladies-underwear#dcp=2&dppp=100&OrderBy=rank";

libxml_use_internal_errors(true); 
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$n  = $xpath->query('//div[@class="s-producttext-top-wrapper"]');
$l  = $xpath->query('//div[@class="s-producttext-top-wrapper"]/a');
$p  = $xpath->query('//div[@class="s-largered"]');
$nl = $xpath->query('//a[@class="swipeNextClick NextLink"]');
$NextLink  = $nl->item(0)->getAttribute("data-dcp");

$item = 0;
foreach ($n as $entry) {
    $Name      = $entry->nodeValue;
    $Link      = $l->item($item)->getAttribute("href");

    $Price     = $p->item($item)->nodeValue;

    $Find = array('Â£');
    $Replace   = array('');

    $Price = str_replace($Find, $Replace, $Price);      

    echo "Name: $Name - Link: $Link - Price: $Price - $NextLink<br>";
$item++;    

}
?>
```

I still get the results for the products of the FIRST page. Why?
How can i parse all the products from Page 2, where is my mistake?

Can you please help me out?

Thanks in advance!